# C++ global vs local variable as a header in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been recently trying to learn C/C++. I have written a simple linked list program that should work and it actually does but only when a header of the linked list (`node* mother`) is a global variable and is not used as a parameter to the function (`void new_node(int number)`) - this function is a constructor (I am using a C syntax).

This program below works fine but I cannot create more than one linked list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


struct node {
    node * next;
    int number;
};


node * mother = NULL;

void new_node(int number)
{
    node * newNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    newNode -> next = NULL;
    newNode -> number = number;

    if (mother == NULL){
        mother = newNode;
    }
    else{
        node* temp = mother;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}

void destroy(){
    node* ntemp = mother;
    mother = NULL;
    node* t;

    while(ntemp != NULL){
        t = ntemp->next;
        free(ntemp);
        ntemp = t;
    }
}

void printAll(){
    node *tmp;
    tmp = mother;
    while (tmp != NULL){
        cout <<"value is : " << tmp->number <<endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

}

int main()
{
    cout <<"size is " << sizeof(node*) <<endl;

    new_node(5);
    new_node(17);
    new_node(-54);
    new_node(3);
    new_node(4);
    new_node(-24);
    new_node(10);
    printAll();
    return 0;
}
```

---

And if I use however `node* mother` as a argument to function `new_node`, it does not work - it only prints the size of a node:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


struct node {
    node * next;
    int number;
};

void new_node(node* mother, int number){
    node * newNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    newNode -> next = NULL;
    newNode -> number = number;

    if (mother == NULL){
        mother = newNode;
    }
    else{
        node* temp = mother;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}

void destroy(node * mother){
    node* ntemp = mother;
    mother = NULL;
    node* t;

    while(ntemp != NULL){
        t = ntemp->next;
        free(ntemp);
        ntemp = t;
    }
}

void printAll(node * mother){
    node *tmp;
    tmp = mother;
    while (tmp != NULL){
        cout <<"value is : " << tmp->number <<endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

}

int main()
{
node * mother = NULL;

    cout <<"size is " << sizeof(node*) <<endl;

    new_node(mother, 5);
    new_node(mother, 17);
    new_node(mother, -54);
    new_node(mother, 3);
    new_node(mother, 4);
    new_node(mother, -24);
    new_node(mother, 10);
    printAll(mother);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**OUTPUT OF THE FIRST PROGRAM:**

```
size is 8
value is : 5
value is : 17
value is : -54
value is : 3
value is : 4
value is : -24
value is : 10
```

---

**OUTPUT OF THE SECOND PROGRAM:**

```
size is 8
```

**The question is, why does this program behave so differently?**

Comment: Don't yell at us, please.

Comment: What does your debugger show you?

Comment: Thank you for Your answers guys. You helped me a lot - I did not mean to yell - just an expression of my frustration - I will make sure to keep it calm next time :).

Comment: Big Thanks, once again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing new_node to this:

```
void new_node(node** mother, int number){
    node * newNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    newNode -> next = NULL;
    newNode -> number = number;

    if (*mother == NULL){
        *mother = newNode;
    }
    else{
        node* temp = *mother;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

and main to this:

```
int main()
{
node * mother = NULL;

    cout <<"size is " << sizeof(node*) <<endl;

    new_node(&mother, 5);
    new_node(&mother, 17);
    new_node(&mother, -54);
    new_node(&mother, 3);
    new_node(&mother, 4);
    new_node(&mother, -24);
    new_node(&mother, 10);
    printAll(mother);
    return 0;
}
```

You should pass pointer to pointer to node in your `new_node` function, because otherwise only copy of `mother` pointer will change in `new_node` function, while `mother` in main will be same.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you set `mother` in this line:

```
mother = newNode;
```

in your `new_node` function, it sets the local copy of `mother`, not the variable you passed in.

You will need to use a reference `node * &mother` or a double pointer `node ** mother` to be able to modify the original `mother` as it was passed in.

Answer (score 0):

The matter is that inside the function called "new_node" You work with just a copy of pointer. So changes are not saved after the function exits. To allow to modify pointer instead of its copy inside of the function You should use the following declaration of Your function:

`void new_node(node*& mother, int number)`

This is the only change to make Your second program work.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `new_node()` a local copy of `mother` is created, and any changes to it are lost when the function exits. This is why your list never gets created.

The easiest fix is to simply change

```
void new_node(node* mother, int number)
```

to

```
void new_node(node* &mother, int number) // pass-by-reference - Google it!
```

and you'll get the result you want. Why? The `&` in `node* &mother` tells the compiler that you want the function to use the actual `mother` variable that you're passing in, and not a copy of it.